# PDF Rendering Error: use checkifodd and variable

Tags: rendering, variable

I use checkifodd and varialbe x, y.

When compiling, error: Something went wrong while rendering this PDF

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.csv}
Acol, Bcol,Ccol
Ax,Bx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,1
A2,B44,2
A3,B11,3
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{mydata1}{test1.csv}

\newcommand*{\x}{\ifoddpage 5cm\else 10cm\fi}
\newcommand*{\y}{\ifoddpage 1cm\else 6cm\fi}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata1}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol,\C=Ccol}%
{%
\checkoddpage{

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (n1)[anchor=north west,xshift=\x,yshift=\y] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

}
}
\end{document}
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouln't use both the `ifoddpage` and `changepage` packages in the same document without first making sure they are compatible, because they both provide at least one command with the same name (namely `\checkoddpage`, but see the note below). I'm sticking with `changepage` here, because it is the one I used in my previous answers to you on these subjects.

Note: regarding this compatibility, the documentation of the `ifoddpage` package says:

> The `changepage` package and the `memoir` class also provide the core functionality of this package, i.e. they define `\checkoddpage` and `\ifoddpage` but no other of the mentioned macros. That package uses this conditional internally in order to allow the user to change the page layout for odd or even pages, which is its main function. The `ifoddpage` [package] should work together with that package and class, but should be loaded last to ensure the correct functionality of `\ifoddpageoroneside`. It also uses labels if it is loaded using the `strict` option.

That said, the real problem in your document is that in order for your `\x` and `\y` macros to produce a 〈dimen〉 (a rigid length), TeX needs to perform two expansion steps, but Ti*k*Z appears to do only one for things written in the optional argument of `\node`. For instance, you can verify that if you do the first expansion step yourself, it works:

```latex
\checkoddpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node (n1) [anchor=north west, xshift=\ifoddpage 5cm\else 10cm\fi,
              yshift=\ifoddpage 1cm\else -6cm\fi]
    at (current page.north west)
    {\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`\ifoddpage 5cm\else 10cm\fi` expands to either `5cm` or `10cm` in one expansion step, and this does work in the optional argument of `\node`. But when you use `\x`, you need one expansion step to obtain `\ifoddpage 5cm\else 10cm\fi` and a second one to obtain either `5cm` or `10cm`. The Ti*k*Z parser doesn't seem to do the two steps (how could it guess how many are needed?).

In order to nicely solve this problem, my suggestion would be to:

- first execute commands such as `\edef` or `\pgfmathsetmacro` that perform full expansion *before* the `\node` command in order to define two macros `\myxshift` and `\myyshift` that need *only one expansion step* to yield the desired result for the current page;
- then use `\myxshift` and `\myyshift` in the `\node` options.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents*}{test1.csv}
Acol, Bcol,Ccol
Ax,Bx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,1
A2,B44,2
A3,B11,3
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{mydata1}{test1.csv}

\newcommand*{\x}{\ifoddpage 5cm\else 10cm\fi}
% I changed 6cm to -6cm here, otherwise the image is invisible (above the
% page!).
\newcommand*{\y}{\ifoddpage 1cm\else -6cm\fi}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata1}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol,\C=Ccol}%
{%
\checkoddpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \edef\myxshift{\x}            % or \pgfmathsetmacro{\myxshift}{\x}
  \edef\myyshift{\y}            % or \pgfmathsetmacro{\myyshift}{\y}

  \node (n1) [anchor=north west, xshift=\myxshift, yshift=\myyshift]
    at (current page.north west)
    {\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Pages]

Comment: thank for you awesom solution. Do you have other solution that can definition "\edef\myxshift{\x}  % or \pgfmathsetmacro{\myxshift}{\x}" before begin{document}? thanks

Comment: I'm afraid not. The result of these commands depend on the last `\checkoddpage` check. If you do them earlier, the result will be wrong.